# Right way to use && and || in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, ecmascript-6

I've made a little web-application. And want to make when I push 'enter' there must be check if there is empty or space value. In this case I have 'alert'.

So I used event listener. But it works incorrect. Alert appears when I push not only 'enter'. Need your help!

```js
const convert = document.getElementById('convert');

currentValue.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13 && currentValue.value === '' ||
    currentValue.value === ' ') {
    alert('value is empty');
  } else {
    convertTemperature();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="application">
  <input id="currentValue" type="number">
  <select id="select">
    <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
    <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
    <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  <button id="convert">Convert</button>
  </br>
  <input id="value1" type="text">
  </br>
  <input id="value2" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Use paretheses, like `event.which === 13 && (currentValue.value === '' || 
currentValue.value === ' ')`

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca, thanks, it works.
But it starts to calculate when I start to print a figure. How to make the calculations after entering figures?

Comment: You should change the `else` to `else if (event.which === 13)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&& has higher priory than || so you have to add () for || condition as following `(currentValue.value === '' || currentValue.value === ' ')`

```
const convert = document.getElementById('convert');

currentValue.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13 )
       if(currentValue.value === '' || currentValue.value === ' ') {
          alert('value is empty');
      } else {   
            convertTemperature();
      }
}, false);
```

Comment: @ Ahmed Yousif, thanks. But it starts to calculate when I start to print a figure. How to make the calculations after entering figures?

Comment: simply add if (event.which === 13) before calculate call I updated it you can use it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below

```js
const convert = document.getElementById('convert');

currentValue.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
   if (currentValue.value === '' ||
    currentValue.value === ' ') {
    alert('value is empty');
  } else {
    convertTemperature();
  }
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="application">
  <input id="currentValue" type="number">
  <select id="select">
    <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
    <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
    <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  <button id="convert">Convert</button>
  </br>
  <input id="value1" type="text">
  </br>
  <input id="value2" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: this explains nothing - never just post code. OP needs to understand the problem, not remember the solution

Answer (score 0):

First you need a `form`, so you don't need to focus on the button and then check for `enter`.

In this case you will only need the operator.

```js
function convertTemp(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let __key = event.keyCode || event.which,
    __ipVal = document.getElementById('currentValue').value;
  if (__ipVal === '' || __ipVal === ' ') {
    alert('value is empty');
  } else {
    console.log('Convert Temp')

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="application">
  <form id='convertTempForm' onsubmit='convertTemp(event)'>
    <input id="currentValue" type="number">
    <select id="select">
      <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
      <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
      <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
    </select>

    <button id="convert" type='submit'>Convert</button>
  </form>
  <div>
    <input id="value1" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="value2" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank U. Can U say how can I output the result in JSON format?